# vimのキーバインドでctrl+;を使いたい

Tags: vim

vimのキーバインドで<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>をインサートモードで利用したいと考えています。

```
inoremap <C-;>
```

で登録しても機能しません。
`C-;`を利用したいので、どのように記述をすればいいのか、分かる方教えて下さい。

Comment: vimを端末上で使っていますか?
端末では`C-;`に該当する文字が無い為、基本的には使えません。
しかし一部の端末ではこれをサポートする為の機能があるので、それに合わせた設定を行えば使えるかもしれません。
使っている端末エミュレータは何でしょうか?

Comment: windowsで香り屋さんの配布しているgvimを利用しています。端末では利用していません。gvimでも`C-;`に該当する文字が無いということでしょうか。

Comment: 対応する文字が無いのは端末の問題なので本来ならばgvimには関係無いのですが、どうもgvimでは`C-;`は使えないようです。どうしても使いたい場合はAutoHotkey等のキーリマップソフトで適当なシーケンスに割り当てて、そのシーケンスをgvim側でmapする等でしょうか。

Answer (score 8):

gvim は端末の文字入力をエミュレートしています。ですので結果から言いますと <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> は使えません。

端末の文字入力で <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> は ASCII 入力コードから -0x20 シフトする(6ビット目を落とす)キーにアサインされています。つまり <kbd>a</kbd> (0x61) は (0x41) <kbd>A</kbd> になります。また <kbd>CTRL</kbd> は ASCII 入力コードを -0x40 シフト(7ビット目を落とす)するためのキーにアサインされています。つまり <kbd>A</kbd> (0x41)に <kbd>CTRL</kbd> を合わせると (0x01) になり、また<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> は 0x08 つまり <kbd>BS</kbd> になるのです。

<kbd>;</kbd> (0x3B) は元々7ビット目が 0 なので <kbd>CTRL</kbd> を合わせても何も変わりません。ですので一般的な端末エミュレータでは <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> は使えません。これと同じ理由で gvim でも <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> は使う事ができません。